# i18n with Cocoapods and dynamic library

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods to add ParseUI library to my Swift (iOS 8) project:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'Garage' do
    pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1'
end
```

I'm adding the library as a dynamic library (use_frameworks!).

The Parse documentation says that I can use the Localizable.string to localize the UI: [Localizing String Resources at ParseUI](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-string/iOS).
I did that but nothing changed.

Is there any way to localize a dynamic library?

PS: I'm using Xcode 6.3, iOS8, swift, cocoapods 0.36.4

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I found a workaround which isn't great if you want support more languages. But if you just want to change the englisch version it is working:

1. open XXXX.xcworkspace
2. go To Pods -> Pods -> ParuseUI -> Ressources -> en.lproj
3. change your labels

Tested with ParseUI 1.2. Would be great to use the normal way with "Localizable.strings" in the project

Comment: update: It seems, that it only works for the labels and buttons - no alert message is localized :/